# html link to relocate google map

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

On a personal blog website I am making, I have the background set as the google map and have a smaller div on top talking about places I've been to etc. What I want to do is have a link like "show place in google map" and when clicked, the background map will be updated to the corresponding location.

I tried making a javascript code

```
<script> function initialize() {
    var mapCanvas = document.getElementById('map-canvas');
    var mapOptions = {
        scrollwheel: false,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(34.0722, -118.4441),
        zoom: 14,
        zoomControlOptions: {
            position: google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_CENTER
        },
        streetViewControl: false,
        panControl: false,
        mapTypeControl: false,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker();
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function() {
        var a = document.getElementsByClassName("map-link");
        a.onclick = function() {
            marker.setMap(map);
        }
    }
</script>

<a class="map-link" href="javascript:void(0)"> Show in Google Maps </a>
```

Something like this, but I'm not seeing any result. Does anybody know how to go about this?

Comment: you should try setting up center of map on click with google.maps.LatLng object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use `map.setCenter` to change the center of the map.
2. getElementsByClassName returns an array of DOM elements.

   google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementsByClassName("map-link")[0], 'click', function (e) {
     map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(42, -72));
   });

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/vLLap1kq/)

**code snippet:**

```js
function initialize() {
  var mapCanvas = document.getElementById('map-canvas');
  var mapOptions = {
    scrollwheel: false,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(34.0722, -118.4441),
    zoom: 14,
    zoomControlOptions: {
      position: google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_CENTER
    },
    streetViewControl: false,
    panControl: false,
    mapTypeControl: false,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }
  var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementsByClassName("map-link")[0], 'click', function(e) {
    map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(42, -72));
  });
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementsByClassName("map-link")[1], 'click', function(e) {
    map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(41, -72.1));
  });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map-canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><a class="map-link" href="javascript:void(0)"> Show in Google Maps </a>
  </li>
  <li><a class="map-link" href="javascript:void(0)"> Show another place in Google Maps </a>
  </li>
</ul>
<div id="map-canvas" style="border: 2px solid #3872ac;"></div>
```